# How to use methods of a declaration which is part of the library located in node-modules in the component created by me

Tags: angular, typescript

I am relatively new in Angular2 and I am facing some problems with using the methods of a declaration class which is part of angular2-grid library which I have installed.

I have created the component **grid.component.ts** as below

```
 import { Component,Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, EventEmitter, ComponentFactoryResolver, Host, ViewEncapsulation, Type, ComponentRef, KeyValueDiffer, KeyValueDiffers, OnInit, OnDestroy, DoCheck, ViewContainerRef, Output } from '@angular/core';
 import { NgGridConfig,NgGridItemEvent, NgGridItemPosition, NgGridItemSize, NgGridRawPosition, NgGridItemDimensions} from 'angular2-grid/interfaces/INgGrid'
 import { NgGrid} from 'angular2-grid/directives/NgGrid'
 import { NgGridItem} from 'angular2-grid/directives/NgGridItem'
 import {  NgGridPlaceholder} from 'angular2-grid/components/NgGridPlaceholder'

  @Component({
   selector: 'pm-app',
   templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./grid.component.css']
    })

 export class GridComponent {

  text = 'Move me'

   // I want to use the method addItem which is declared in *NgGrid.d.ts*
  public addItem(ngItem: NgGridItem): void {
    alert("angular2-grid will be added")
  }
  /*NgGridConfig is a interface which is declared also in angular2-grid which itself is located to node-modules
  */
  private gridConfig = <NgGridConfig>{
    'margins': [5],
    'draggable': true,
    'resizable': true,
    'max_cols': 5,
    'max_rows': 0,
    'visible_cols': 0,
    'visible_rows': 0,
    'min_cols': 1,
    'min_rows': 1,
    'col_width': 250,
    'row_height': 250,
    'cascade': 'up',
    'min_width': 100,
    'min_height': 100,
    'fix_to_grid': false,
    'auto_style': true,
    'auto_resize': true,
    'maintain_ratio': false, 
    'prefer_new': false
    };
pageTitle: string = "A product for our company";
 }
```

grid.component.html is as below:

```
   <div [ngGrid]="gridConfig">
      <div [ngGridItem]="{'dragHandle': '.handle', 'fixed': true, 'col': 2, 'row': 1, 'minWidth': 30}">
        <div class="handle">{{text}}</div>
       </div>
    </div>
      <h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
    <div>
      <pm-product></pm-product>
   </div>
```

I am able to use in my html file **gridConfig** which is created in grid.component.ts and hold an Object of **NgGridConfig** but I am not able to use methods of NgGrid.d.ts. One method of this declaration file I want to use is **addItem** but I do not know how to use this method in my grid.component.ts. Moreover I am also not able to bind it on my html file as I can bind **grindConfig**.

Below I copy paste the interface **INgGrid.d.ts** and the directive **NgGrid.d.ts**

NgGrid.d.ts:

```
 import { ElementRef, Renderer, EventEmitter, ComponentFactoryResolver, KeyValueDiffers, OnInit, OnDestroy, DoCheck, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgGridConfig, NgGridItemEvent, NgGridItemPosition, NgGridItemSize } from '../interfaces/INgGrid';
import { NgGridItem } from './NgGridItem';
export declare class NgGrid implements OnInit, DoCheck, OnDestroy {
private _differs;
private _ngEl;
private _renderer;
private componentFactoryResolver;
private _containerRef;
onDragStart: EventEmitter<NgGridItem>;
onDrag: EventEmitter<NgGridItem>;
onDragStop: EventEmitter<NgGridItem>;
onResizeStart: EventEmitter<NgGridItem>;
onResize: EventEmitter<NgGridItem>;
onResizeStop: EventEmitter<NgGridItem>;
onItemChange: EventEmitter<Array<NgGridItemEvent>>;
colWidth: number;
rowHeight: number;
minCols: number;
minRows: number;
marginTop: number;
marginRight: number;
marginBottom: number;
marginLeft: number;
isDragging: boolean;
isResizing: boolean;
autoStyle: boolean;
resizeEnable: boolean;
dragEnable: boolean;
cascade: string;
minWidth: number;
minHeight: number;
private _items;
private _draggingItem;
private _resizingItem;
private _resizeDirection;
private _itemGrid;
private _containerWidth;
private _containerHeight;
private _maxCols;
private _maxRows;
private _visibleCols;
private _visibleRows;
private _setWidth;
private _setHeight;
private _posOffset;
private _adding;
private _placeholderRef;
private _fixToGrid;
private _autoResize;
private _differ;
private _destroyed;
private _maintainRatio;
private _aspectRatio;
private _preferNew;
private _zoomOnDrag;
private _limitToScreen;
private _curMaxRow;
private _curMaxCol;
private _dragReady;
private _resizeReady;
private static CONST_DEFAULT_CONFIG;
private _config;
config: NgGridConfig;
constructor(_differs: KeyValueDiffers, _ngEl: ElementRef, _renderer: Renderer, componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, _containerRef: ViewContainerRef);
ngOnInit(): void;
ngOnDestroy(): void;
setConfig(config: NgGridConfig): void;
getItemPosition(index: number): NgGridItemPosition;
getItemSize(index: number): NgGridItemSize;
ngDoCheck(): boolean;
setMargins(margins: Array<string>): void;
enableDrag(): void;
disableDrag(): void;
enableResize(): void;
disableResize(): void;

**public addItem(ngItem: NgGridItem): void** 
removeItem(ngItem: NgGridItem): void;
updateItem(ngItem: NgGridItem): void 
triggerCascade(): void;
```

INgGrid.d.ts:

```
   export interface NgGridConfig {
     margins?: number[];
     draggable?: boolean;
     resizable?: boolean;
     max_cols?: number;
     max_rows?: number;
     visible_cols?: number;
     visible_rows?: number;
     min_cols?: number;
     min_rows?: number;
     col_width?: number;
     row_height?: number;
     cascade?: string;
     min_width?: number;
     min_height?: number;
     fix_to_grid?: boolean;
     auto_style?: boolean;
     auto_resize?: boolean;
     maintain_ratio?: boolean;
     prefer_new?: boolean;
     zoom_on_drag?: boolean;
     limit_to_screen?: boolean;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to take advantage of Angular's dependency injection and the @ViewChild decorator.

In your Grid class,

```
export class GridComponent {

  @ViewChild(NgGrid)
  grid: NgGrid;

  text = 'Move me'

  // I want to use the method addItem which is declared in *NgGrid.d.ts*
  public addItem(ngItem: NgGridItem): void {
    // i can now call grid.addItem(ngItem) here 
    // remember, grid is the instance of NgGrid created with your component
    alert("angular2-grid will be added")
  }
   .....
}
```

Angular will search your component's view for an instance of the NgGrid directive, and inject it into the grid member variable. At that point, you have an instance of NgGrid to call whatever you need to call.

see: [Angular's ViewChild Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html)

Comment: Doing what you have done does it mean than addItem now can be bind at html file? How can I bind the function addItem of NgGrid declaration in html? I will appreciate your helo

Comment: Not sure of the question - doing the above will give you the NgGrid object that was created when Angular created your component. I'll update the answer showing you how you'd call a method in NgGrid